# Freeradius Max-Daily-Session in custom authentication

Tags: php, freeradius

Actually i have AAA by mysql and everything work fine. Especially the use **Max-Daily-Session** attribute to disconnect the user after 10min (600sec) connection.
I recently changed the way authenticazione using a custom php script.
In sites-enabled/default file:

```
authorize{
update control { 
    Auth-Type := `/usr/bin/php -f /etc/raddb/yourscript.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '%{Client-IP-Address}'`
}
```

In /etc/freeradius/users:

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type = Accept
Exec-Program-Wait = "/usr/bin/php -f  /etc/raddb/attributes.php '%{User-Name}' '%{User-Password}' '%{Client-IP-Address}'"
```

In attributes.php:

```
<?php
$User = $argv[1];
$Pass = $argv[2];
$Ip   = $argv[3];
if ($User == "test")
    echo "Max-Daily-Session:=600";
?>
```

It seems that the server does not care about the Max-Daily-Session attribute and does not send the Packet of Disconnect. What changes between mysql and custom authentication?

Answer (score 0):

What is your nas? The method of radius Session-Timeout is:

1. user A login to radius by nas
2. radius reply `Session-Timeout 600s` to nas
3. after 600s, nas disconnect user A. It is not radius send Packet of Disconnect to nas.

You should use attribute `Session-Timeout := 600`.